# Node.js server just keeps loading with no result.

Tags: javascript, node.js, postdata

I have been trying to get my server to work but when I send post data it just keeps loading and no results are given.  Here is my noen.js file.

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

// Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  var queryData = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});

  if (queryData.name) {
    // user told us their name in the GET request, ex: http://host:8000/?name=Tom
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    function puts(error, stdout, stderr) {sys.puts(stdout)}
    exec ("casperjs test.js " + queryData.name + '\n');

  } else {
response.end("Contact Admin - Not Working\n");
  }
});

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(1213);
```

Can anyone help me fix this? When I go to

```
127.0.0.1:8000/?name=tom
```

I get no response the page just goes into a long loading loop

Comment: Try adding response.end("hello there"); after the call to exec(). You are never sending a response in this case.

Comment: how can I get it to respond with the result of th actual exec command

Comment: @HectorCorrea This does help with the constant loading but I need to also have the result of the exec command echoed aswel can you please help me do that

Comment: Try this: `response.end(exec('casperjs test.js ' + queryData.name + '\n'));`.

Comment: @srikarg this just throws me an error bro

Comment: What's the error? Also, did you try setting a variable equal to the result from the `exec` method and then passing that to `response.end()`?

Comment: I am new to node js any chance you could write an answer using my above code so I can understand it better please and thanks

Comment: @srikarg basically when I send post data I get no page loaded could you please write an answer using my code above please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no response.end in case if is true so then response "never" ends.
write at bottom of the if

```
response.end("something");
```

And you will get the response;

For get the output of the process to the response:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3944751/3018595

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

// Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  var queryData = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});

  if (queryData.name) {
    // user told us their name in the GET request, ex: http://host:8000/?name=Tom
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;

    exec ("casperjs test.js " + queryData.name + '\n',function(err, stdout, stderr) {

        response.end(stdout);

    });

  } else {
    response.end("Contact Admin - Not Working\n");
  }
});

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(1213);
```

Comment: this does not fix the full problem and you have only copied what srikarg has said in our comments above

Comment: Sorry but I haven't copied it. Your question is ambiguous. If you want to get the output of the casper process to the response you could pipe the casper process stdout stream.

http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_stdout

Comment: that's exactly what I want to do I want to get the response of casperjs could  you show me an example of piping the stdout stream

Comment: hows that this is my last part of my script and I am racking my brains learning this code

Comment: sorry I just don't understand how I could do this at the moment if yu could show and example using my code above I would be so greatfull

Answer (score 0):

The reason your browser is keep waiting because you are not ending your response. You have to call response.end to let your server complete the response otherwise it will keep thinking that the response is not complete yet. I added a line in your if statement and tested your code and it is working perfectly fine.

added line ** response.end("Request processed successfully...\n");**, assuming that you need to display a different message in case your "else" statement.
I tested url http://:1213/?name=tom

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

// Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
var queryData = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});

if (queryData.name) {
// user told us their name in the GET request, ex: http://host:8000/?name=Tom
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
function puts(error, stdout, stderr) {sys.puts(stdout)}
exec ("casperjs test.js " + queryData.name + '\n');
response.end("Request processed successfully...\n");   


} else {
response.end("Contact Admin - Not Working\n");
}
});

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(1213);
```

Comment: Do you know how I can pipe the stdout from casperjs ?

Comment: Sorry no experience with casperjs.