# Want to display output on browser, Running http://localhost:8000/ will download the file instead of viewing on browser?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to run my node js program on port 8000, but it downloads the output instead of viewing on the browser.

```
var http = require('http'); 
function onRequest(request, response){ 
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'plain/text'}); 
    response.write("hi");
    response.end(); 
} 
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8000);
```

Comment: what's the mime type when you are serving the page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download a file from NodeJS Server using Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288814/download-a-file-from-nodejs-server-using-express)

Comment: post your full code

Comment: type is plain/text

Comment: This is my full code, Sorry there is an issue with alignment in this textbox...var http = require('http');

function onRequest(request, response){
 response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : 'plain/text'});
 response.write("hi");
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8000);

Comment: Please update your question with the code what you have tried.

Comment: when i am trying to run this code it will run and downloads the file not viewing on browser

Comment: [Read data on browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3932980/nodejs-stream-output-to-browser) This may answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring as you have you MIME types off. You are using `plain/text`, whereas the correct MIME type is `text/plain`. I've flagged to close this question due to it's typographical rather than logical error, but I will leave a note regarding what some others have noted in the comments of the question, just to provide a little tidbit on the matter for anyone who might stumble across this question.

Many of the commenters are correct in stating that some major browsers assume that the MIME type `text/plain` is meant for file downloads, as many servers are incorrectly configured to return `text/plain` for certain files. Some browsers, as have been noted, will attempt to "sniff" the data attempts to deduce if the correct MIME type is being used. This has been mainly seen in Chrome and Internet Explorer. Firefox saw it for quite some time in regards to links to stylesheets with incorrect MIME types, but it has since been removed for foreign URL's for security purposes. The simplest way around this is to add the `X-Content-Type-Options` header to the response, and give it a value of `nosniff`. This will help to prevent browsers from attempting to guess the MIME type, which can sometimes produce unintended results, albeit not in this instance.

Comment: Yes, Correct MIME type is text/plain, but still my problem is not solved, Because output is not displaying on my browser, so question is not closed..

Comment: What browser are you using? Please include the version. @TusharWaghmode

Comment: I am using Google chrome browser and having version 63.0.3239.108 (64-bit)